# Unable to open zip with ZipArchive

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I'm running a php script (like bash).
This script do this:

- Download a zip file from FTP server

ftp_get($ftp, $myFile.zip, $file, FTP_BINARY);

When I have downloaded the file, I want to extract its content:

```
   $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $zip->open($myFile);

    if ($res === TRUE) {
        $zip->extractTo($extractDir);
        $zip->close();

    } else {
        dump( 'error, code:' . $res);
        die;
    }
```

But, I get the error 19 who is: "Not a zip archive"
If I open the .zip, it is a compressed archive because I have the PK key...

Does anyone have a solution or idea ?

Regards

Comment: What is this variable $myFile for you ? You need send a path of this file not a binary.

Comment: does the file is encrypted using password?

Comment: $myFile is the path of the file, like D:/myFile.zip
The file is not encrypted.. :)

Comment: all looks fine in your code...can you creating a zip file by yourself and then try in this code. If you are running this code just after downloading from sFTP then it may cause a lock in file as file is being created by php and os. You can try writing sleep(10) in your code..however using sleep in code is not a good idea as it will impact on performance.

Comment: Problem resolved. The file was corrupted... The server's hardrive was full and the .zip created was corrupted. Thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

#### Solutions

I am using this code and it work fine.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$myfileDir = './abc.zip';
$extractDir = './';

$res = $zip->open($myfileDir);

if ($res === TRUE) {
  $zip->extractTo($extractDir);
  $zip->close();

  echo 'Successfully extract the file';
} else {
  echo ('error, code:' . $res);
  die;
}
```

#### Question

I believe the problem is because of the zip file, would upload the the zip folder to google drive and let us download and test it locally?